# Select abrir janela com opções do banco

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

Preciso de uma ajuda, tenho um código que ao clicar no `checkbox` aparecia uma janela, se desmarca-se a janela sumia, até ai tudo bem, só que agora, não vai ser mais um `checkbox` que controla-rá a exibição da janela.

Vai ser um `select` e suas opções deverão vir do banco de dados(Postgre).

Tenho que pegar as 3 opções que vem do banco e colocar para abrir e fechar essa janela.

Esse e meu select:

```
<div class="es2 col-md-6">
   <label class="lb">
      Nacionalidade
   </label>
   <select ng-model="pessoa.pessoasFisicas.nacionalidade.idNacionalidade" ng-options="nac.idNacionalidade as nac.descricao for nac in nacionalidades " class=" js-example-theme-single1"  style="width: 100%; margin-top: -3px;" placeholder="Digite aqui nacionalidade">
      <option  ></option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Essa sao as janelas que tem que abrir e fechar no caso sao abas ne.

```
<li>
   <a data-toggle="tab"   id="tabEstrangeiro"  data-target="#estrangeiro">
       Estrangeiro
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a data-toggle="tab"  id="tabNaturalizado"  data-target="#naturalizado">
      Naturalizado
   </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

O seguinte código deve te ajudar, qualquer dúvida ou parte que falte é só me avisares:

```js
function selectMudou() {
  var select = document.getElementById('opcoes');
  switch ( select.options[select.selectedIndex].text ) {
    case 'Opção 1': // caso seja a opção 1
      document.getElementById('tabEstrangeiro').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('tabNaturalizado').style.display = 'initial';
      break;
    case 'Opção 2': // caso seja a opção 2
      document.getElementById('tabEstrangeiro').style.display = 'initial';
      document.getElementById('tabNaturalizado').style.display = 'none';
      break;
    case 'Opção 3': // caso seja a opção 3
      document.getElementById('tabEstrangeiro').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('tabNaturalizado').style.display = 'none';
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
#esconder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="opcoes" onchange="selectMudou()">
  <option id="esconder">Escolhe</option>
  <option>Opção 1</option>
  <option>Opção 2</option>
  <option>Opção 3</option>
</select>
<li>
  <a data-toggle="tab" id="tabEstrangeiro" data-target="#estrangeiro">Estrangeiro</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a data-toggle="tab" id="tabNaturalizado" data-target="#naturalizado">Naturalizado</a>
</li>
```

**Editado (função para mudar as opções):**

```js
function mudarOpcoes(novasOpcoes) {
  var select = document.getElementById('opcoes');
  var opcoes = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
  for ( let i = 0; i < opcoes.length - 1; i++ ) {
    opcoes[i + 1].innerText = novasOpcoes[i];
  }
}

var novasOpcoes = ['Dados', 'da', 'BD'];

mudarOpcoes(novasOpcoes);
```

```css
#esconder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="opcoes" onchange="selectMudou()">
  <option id="esconder">Escolhe</option>
  <option>Opção 1</option>
  <option>Opção 2</option>
  <option>Opção 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sim mais como pedido tbm querob ao invez de ter o options e ter esse option vindo do banco de dados, que vem dinamicamente entende, no caso quero saber como pegar esse valor e colocar nos meu li, pra depois fazer aparecer e sumir

Comment: @DiegoLauraSoares Queres que as opções venham de uma base de dados, é isso?

Comment: sim e eu consiga pegar as opcoes e usa-las pra fazer algo no html como abrir e fechar aqueles li em cima entende. no caso ja esta vindo do banco nao sei como pegar e usa-las pois nao sei como pegar um id ou uma classe pra fazer a função

Comment: @DiegoLauraSoares Eu editei a minha resposta e acrescentei uma função que aceita uma array/vetor com 3 dados e que modifica as opções para esses. A parte de ir buscar os dados à base de dados é mais complicado e para eu te ajudar com isso eu preciso saber qual o nome da base de dados, da tabela e das colunas que contêm os novas opções.

Answer (score 0):

Sim otima ajuda, mais quero tambem ao invez de ter o options e ter esse option vindo do banco de dados, que vem dinamicamente entende, no caso quero saber como pegar esse valor e colocar nos meu li, pra depois fazer aparecer e sumir